# Do all missile modules use Titanium-70 in Endless Space?

Tags: endless-space

Here is the in-game information about Titanium-70. I have 5 units under my control, and would therefore like to take advantage of the 60% industry bonus to quickly mass an army.

[image: Titanium-70]

The [Endless Space Wiki](http://endlessspace.wikia.com/wiki/Titanium-70) states:

> Titanium-70 is usually the first strategic resource researched by N-Way Fusion Plants. It is crucial for the development of missile technology and therefore Titanium-70 is needed to produce ships equipped with torpedoes and missiles.

This certainly seems true for Ion Torpedoes:

[image: Ion Torpedoes]

However, the information card for Unstable Torpedoes seems to contradict the Wiki. No Ti-70 requirement is listed:

[image: Unstable Torpedoes]

In fact, according to the research page, Ion Torpedoes is the *only* module that needs Titanium-70! What should I believe? Should I assume that all missiles require Ti-70, and will benefit from the industry bonus? Or should I lade up my ships with Ion Torpedoes to take advantage of an extremely limited bonus?

Comment: I've wondered about this too.  Notice that the Ion Torpedoes have a cost of 1.2 (!) while the Unstable Torpedoes have a cost of 5.  It certainly seems like only the Ion Torpedoes are affected.

Comment: That's an excellent point; I hadn't noticed that. The Endless Space Wiki puts their raw cost at 6 and 10, a 60% ratio. Here it's a 24% ratio, indicating that the balance has been shifted to favor Ion Torpedoes. I think you're right! Hopefully they patch that somehow, either by extending the number of modules that use Ti-70, or by explicitly stating that the manufacturing bonus applies to Ion Torpedoes specifically, rather than "modules that use Ti-70".

Comment: After playing some more, there are lots of modules like this (at least one of each type) where it requires the material but gets a cost advantage the more you have.  Pretty sure it's by-design.

Comment: Interesting. So the way this is set up, Unstable Torpedoes don't obsolete Ion Torpedoes. I can either have stronger ships that take longer to build with UTs, or have weaker ships faster with ITs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK only Ion Torpedoes make use of the production bonus. Maybe in the future (or in some expansion or DLC) they add further modules, but anyhow Ion Torpedoes are really good in the early game to establish a significant firepower difference. Later on (early to mid game), as your production capabilities get better, the production bonus gets less and less significant compared to the loss of firepower you get from using them.

Answer (score 1):

Only Ion Torpedoes require Titanium-70. If you don't have any Titanium-70 early on, you can push through the military tree to reach the second tier missiles, Unstable Torpedoes.